# How to iterate over Google Analytics profile ID's?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-sheets

I have set up my google analytics API to generate a report within google sheets and feed it data from the given analytics view (profile) ID. I know that you can only run a report from one ID, so I would like to use JS to iterate through all 35 of them. I know enough JS to loop through a grouping, but how would I call the ID's? I will be using the google app script since it is already integrated. any ideas? thanks in advance!

*EDIT
so here is a little more detail. i have a google analytics account that monitors about 35 sites (all unique profile ID's that i have listed and have permissions to). those stats have been manually added to a google sheets doc up until this point. i want to grab the data from each of those Profile ID's and populate an existing spreadsheet without having to run 35 individual reports, which will create 35 individual sheets. i am already able to pull the reports one by one; writing a script to iterate through all the profiles and populating an existing spreadsheet (all my efforts thus far have just created new tabs on the existing sheet) is what i am wrestling with. thank you for your patience and time! happy holidays!

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking - if your view ids are fixed you can simply create an array and iterate that. As an alternative you can create a widget that allows you to select from your authenticated accounts/properties, or you can do something in between (in terms of effort spent).  Can you be a bit more specific how do you want this to work ?

Comment: they are fixed. i didint know if i had to manually create an array or if the analytics API would pass them to me. still trying to figure it all out, i am new to working with api's. i will edit my original question to try to make it more clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are copy/pasted from a Google Spreadsheet I use a few functions, one that lists all accounts for which the user is authenticated, one that returns all properties in an account (pass in account id as parameter) and one that lists all views in a property of a given account (pass in property and account id as parameter). The functions are written to return JSON objects where each element containts key/value pairs for name and (internal) id. Simply use the output of previous functions as parameters for the subsequent functions.

Note that for historical reasons the function that return the view info is named `Analytics.Management.Profiles.list`, "profiles" being what views used to be called before Universal Analytics.

```
/* Generates a list of accounts that are accessible to the currently logged in user */
function listAccounts() {
    var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
    var items = accounts.getItems();
    var item;
    var accountList = [];
    if (items) {
        for (i = 0, cnt = items.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            accountList.push({
                "name": item.name,
                "id": item.id
            });
        }
    }
    return accountList;
}

/* .... and all the properties in those accounts .. */
function listProperties(accountId) {

    var webProperties = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(accountId);
    var items = webProperties.getItems();
    var item;
    var propertyList = [];
    if (items) {
        for (i = 0, cnt = items.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            propertyList.push({
                "name": item.name,
                "id": item.id
            });
        }
    }
    return propertyList;
}


/* And all data view in the selected property */
function listViews(accountId, propertyId) {
    var views = Analytics.Management.Profiles.list(accountId, propertyId);
    var items = views.getItems();
    var item;
    var viewList = [];
    if (items) {
        for (i = 0, cnt = items.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            viewList.push({
                "name": item.name,
                "id": item.id
            });
        }
    }
    return viewList;
}
```

Comment: thank you! i will modify this a bit and see how it works!